# Android: start navigation in walking mode

Tags: android, android-intent, navigation

I'm trying to start an Intent for a navigation:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=" + item.getPoint().getLatitudeE6()/1E6 + ","+item.getPoint().getLongitudeE6()/1E6)));
```

This works fine, but the navigation starts in driving mode. How do I start the navigation in walking mode?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This should work fine:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=your+address&mode=w"));
       startActivity(intent);
```

Regards.