# Google Glass GDK - Specify Mode in navigation Intent

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

Is it possible to specify a transportation mode for the navigation App when launching from an Intent?  i.e. start navigation with walking directions.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("google.navigation:q="+lat+","+lon));
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add **&mode=w** to the end of your google.navigation query string:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("google.navigation:q="+lat+","+lon + "&mode=w"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Note - Glass appears to launch Navigation in the mode last used, so to ensure this is working you will need to make sure you are not already navigating in walk mode.

See [Android: start navigation in walking mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10742710/android-start-navigation-in-walking-mode) for original tip that I tested with Glass and the GDK.

Comment: How can I open the intent to show the navigation between to distinct locations? The above codes assumes source location to be the current location. But what if my source location is a differenct lat,long ?